# Activity doesn't restart on orientation change when window size is 2/3 in multi-window mode

Tags: android, user-interface, multi-window

I am having issues with orientation change in multi-window mode.
The activity doesn't restart on changing orientation when the window size is 2/3 (in multi-window mode) in a tablet device. My layout looks improper due to that.

The activity restarts properly while changing orientation when the window size is 1/2 or 1/3 the display size in multi window mode.
I tried and confirmed this with Nexus 7 and Pixel C devices in (Android Studio) Emulator with Oreo and Pie images.

My app is targeting Oreo 8.1 and I am not using 'android:configChanges' or 'android:screenOrientation' in the manifest.

Note that 2/3 window size is not square and there is a small change in screen size in both orientation and if the orientation change doesn't trigger than the screensize change should trigger activity restart.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Start app in debug mode in a tablet device.
2. Put breakpoints inside onCreate and onResume.
3. Put it in multi-window mode (default 1/2 size).
4. Rotate the device and check if breakpoints trigger (it would).
5. Resize window size to 2/3.
6. Rotate the device and check if breakpoints trigger (it doesn't!).

Am I missing something which is causing this issue? or is this a bug or something else? How can I make my activity restart in this case?

Comment: i'm noticing that on R the activity is not only not recreated, but doesn't even go through `onStart`/`onStop`. also there's only ½ screen split screen stop on my device

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An interesting question, I never knew that there are exceptions to the orientation change process. I was able to reproduce the problem with a Pixel C emulator(Android 8.1) and an app targeting API level 26.

I suppose your screen is not just another list because in this case the difference of 12 pixels (1688 vs. 1676 if I can trust [LayoutInspector](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/layout-inspector)) would not matter, so I wanted to add an observation which may be helpful:

My app contains a custom `View`, and from the logs I can see that its methods `onMeasure()` and `onLayout()` are called even if the `Activity`'s`onCreate()` is not. So this is where you can step in and do some fine tuning.

Another option is to force the `Activity` to be recreated. You could do so by calling the `Activity` method `recreate()` (documented [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#recreate())) as soon as you detect that the screen dimensions have changed. To keep track of the screen size changes, you can create a custom `ViewGroup` overriding `onLayout()` and use this as the root of your `Activity`'s layout file.

Comment: Thanks, with the help of the info you provided I was able to recreate (restart) the Activity when it didn't automatically (2/3 window size).